# Insert Python Dictionary using Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

What is the best way to insert a Python dictionary with many keys into a Postgres database without having to enumerate all keys?

I would like to do something like...

```
song = dict()
song['title'] = 'song 1'
song['artist'] = 'artist 1'
...

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO song_table (song.keys()) VALUES (song)')
```

Answer (score 52):

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

song = {
    'title': 'song 1',
    'artist': 'artist 1'
}

columns = song.keys()
values = [song[column] for column in columns]

insert_statement = 'insert into song_table (%s) values %s'

    # cursor.execute(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
print cursor.mogrify(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
```

Prints:

```
insert into song_table (artist,title) values ('artist 1', 'song 1')
```

Psycopg adapts a `tuple` to a `record` and [`AsIs`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) does what would be done by Python's string substitution.

Comment: Didn't know about `AsIs`. Interesting -- saves needing to deal with the multiplied-out `%s`s...

Comment: I was concerned this may leave the user vulnerable to injection attacks due to inadequate escaping, but - at least using a basic example - single apostrophes appear to be properly escaped. I don't have time to test more advanced injection techniques, such as (or similar to) the ones described at the following link, so they may still be a concern vs. more standard parameterization techniques. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2540707

Comment: why not just use song.values() for the values?  :)

Comment: If I want to get the id of that inserted row, then what to do?

Comment: Getting mogrify requires a psycopg2.extensions.cursor but received a 'str' for insert_statement which is clearly a string.

Comment: It looks like this was written in python2, before dictionaries were ordered. Nowadays, you can use .keys() and .values() and order will be maintained.

Answer (score 35):

You can also insert multiple rows using a `dictionary`. If you had the following:

```
namedict = ({"first_name":"Joshua", "last_name":"Drake"},
            {"first_name":"Steven", "last_name":"Foo"},
            {"first_name":"David", "last_name":"Bar"})
```

You could insert all three rows within the dictionary by using:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES (%(first_name)s, %(last_name)s)""", namedict)
```

The `cur.executemany` statement will automatically iterate through the dictionary and execute the INSERT query for each row.

PS: This example is taken from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial)

Comment: Hi vikas, any comparison on performance against cursor.execute() within loop ?

Comment: Is there a similar solution that leverages mogrify for the performance benefits?

Answer (score 16):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
song = dict()
song['title'] = 'song 1'
song['artist'] = 'artist 1'

cols=song.keys();

vals = [song[x] for x in cols]
vals_str_list = ["%s"] * len(vals)
vals_str = ", ".join(vals_str_list)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO song_table ({cols}) VALUES ({vals_str})".format(
               cols = cols, vals_str = vals_str), vals)
```

The key part is the generated string of `%s` elements, and using that in `format`, with the list passed directly to the `execute` call, so that *psycopg2* can interpolate each item in the `vals` list (thus preventing possible *SQL Injection*).

Another variation, passing the `dict` to `execute`, would be to use these lines instead of `vals`, `vals_str_list` and `vals_str` from above:

```
vals_str2 = ", ".join(["%({0})s".format(x) for x in cols])

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO song_table ({cols}) VALUES ({vals_str})".format(
               cols = cols, vals_str = vals_str2), song)
```

Comment: I would also replace `cols` with `[cursor.mogrify(x) for x in cols]`, and the same for `vals_str`, to thwart SQL injections.

Comment: Agreed that that would certainly add extra protection.

Comment: Reading the psycopg2 doc a bit, `mogrify` may be unnecessary, as the defintion of that method says that **The string returned is exactly the one that would be sent to the database running the execute() method or similar.**, so I think the columns and `%s` strings will be `mogrify`'ed during the `execute` call.

Comment: I think the main difference would be whether it did it up front, before calling `execute`, or during the `execute` itself. If done before, it would essentially just return the same string during the `execute` run, since it would've already been mogrified. If you wanted to know exactly what was going over the wire, say, for your logs, it may be beneficial to do ahead of time.

Answer (score 9):

The new `sql` module was created for this purpose and added in psycopg2 version 2.7. According to the documentation:

> If you need to generate dynamically an SQL query (for instance choosing dynamically a table name) you can use the facilities provided by the psycopg2.sql module.

Two examples are given in the documentation: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

```
names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

q1 = sql.SQL("insert into table ({}) values ({})").format(
    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, names)),
    sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(names)))
print(q1.as_string(conn))
```

> insert into table ("foo", "bar", "baz") values (%s, %s, %s)

```
q2 = sql.SQL("insert into table ({}) values ({})").format(
    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, names)),
    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder, names)))
print(q2.as_string(conn))
```

> insert into table ("foo", "bar", "baz") values (%(foo)s, %(bar)s, %(baz)s)

Though string concatenation would produce the same result, it should not be used for this purpose, according to psycopg2 documentation:

> **Warning**: Never, **never**, **NEVER** use Python string concatenation (`+`) or string parameters interpolation (`%`) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Answer (score 1):

an other approach for **query to mySQL or pgSQL from dictionary** is using construction `%(dic_key)s`, it will be replaced by value from dictionary coresponding by dic_key like `{'dic_key': 'dic value'}`
working perfect, and prevent sqlInjection
tested: Python 2.7 
see below:

```
# in_dict = {u'report_range': None, u'report_description': None, 'user_id': 6, u'rtype': None, u'datapool_id': 1, u'report_name': u'test suka 1', u'category_id': 3, u'report_id': None}


cursor.execute('INSERT INTO report_template (report_id, report_name, report_description, report_range, datapool_id, category_id, rtype, user_id) VALUES ' \
                                                                 '(DEFAULT, %(report_name)s, %(report_description)s, %(report_range)s, %(datapool_id)s, %(category_id)s, %(rtype)s, %(user_id)s) ' \
                                                                 'RETURNING "report_id";', in_dict)
```

---

OUT:
`INSERT INTO report_template (report_id, report_name, report_description, report_range, datapool_id, category_id, rtype, user_id) VALUES (DEFAULT, E'test suka 1', NULL, NULL, 1, 3, NULL, 6) RETURNING "report_id";`

Answer (score 1):

Clodaldos answer gets simpler with python3's "ordered dict" promise:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

song = dict(title='song 1', artist='artist 1')

insert_statement = 'insert into song_table (%s) values %s'
cursor.execute(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(song.keys())), tuple(song.values())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `execute_values` https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html is faster and has a `fetch` argument to return something. Next there is some code that might help.
columns is a string like `col_name1, col_name2`
template is the one that allows the matching, a string like `%(col_name1)s, %(col_name2)`

```
def insert(cur: RealDictCursor,
        table_name: str,
        values: list[dict],
        returning: str = ''
        ):
    if not values:
        return []

    query = f"""SELECT
                    column_name AS c
                FROM
                    information_schema.columns
                WHERE
                    table_name = '{table_name}'
                AND column_default IS NULL;"""
    cur.execute(query)
    columns_names = cur.fetchall()

    fetch = False
    if returning:
        returning = f'RETURNING {returning}'
        fetch = True

    columns = ''
    template = ''
    for col in columns_names:
        col_name = col['c']
        for val in values:
            if col_name in val:
                continue
            val[col_name] = None

        columns += f'{col_name}, '
        template += f'%({col_name})s, '
    else:
        columns = columns[:-2]
        template = template[:-2]

    query = f"""INSERT INTO {table_name} 
                    ({columns})
                    VALUES %s {returning}"""
    return execute_values(cur, query, values,
                        template=f'({template})', fetch=fetch)
```

Answer (score -3):

Python has certain inbuilt features such as **join** and **list** using which one can generate the query. Also,the python dictionary offers **keys()** and **values()** which can be used to extract column name and column values respectively. **This is the approach I used and this should work.**

```
song = dict()
song['title'] = 'song 1'
song['artist'] = 'artist 1'

query = '''insert into song_table (''' +','.join(list(song.keys()))+''') values '''+ str(tuple(song.values()))
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea. To quote the psycopg documentation: "Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."