# psycopg2 - Inserting list of dictionaries into PosgreSQL database. Too many executions?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am inserting a list of dictionaries to a PostgreSQL database. The list will be growing quickly and the number of dict values (columns) is around 30. The simplified data:

```
projects = [
{'name': 'project alpha', 'code': 12, 'active': True},
{'name': 'project beta', 'code': 25, 'active': True},
{'name': 'project charlie', 'code': 46, 'active': False}
]
```

Inserting the data into the PostgreSQL database with the following code does work (as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29471241/7547749)), but I am worried about executing too many queries.

```py
for project in projects:
    columns = project.keys()
    values = project.values()

    query = """INSERT INTO projects (%s) VALUES %s;"""

    # print(cursor.mogrify(query, (AsIs(','.join(project.keys())), tuple(project.values()))))

    cursor.execute(query, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))

conn.commit()
```

Is there a better practice? Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use copy statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271787/psycopg2-postgresql-python-fastest-way-to-bulk-insert

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [execute_values()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) to insert many rows in a single query.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

# ...

projects = [
{'name': 'project alpha', 'code': 12, 'active': True},
{'name': 'project beta', 'code': 25, 'active': True},
{'name': 'project charlie', 'code': 46, 'active': False}
]

columns = projects[0].keys()
query = "INSERT INTO projects ({}) VALUES %s".format(','.join(columns))

# convert projects values to list of lists
values = [[value for value in project.values()] for project in projects]

execute_values(cursor, query, values)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Cool. Got 30% performance gain with just a few rows already. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another performant option that does not require so much data munging for a list of dictionaries is execute_batch (new in psycopg2 version 2.7).

For example:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch

values = [{'name': 'project alpha', 'code': 12, 'active': True}, ...]
query = "INSERT INTO projects VALUES (%(name)s, %(code)s, %(active)s)"

execute_batch(cursor, query, values)
conn.commit()
```

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch

Comment: should be `values = [{'name': ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use bulk loading to make it faster.

https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2017/11/08/faster-bulk-loading-in-postgresql-with-copy/