# update python dictionary to postgres db table using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a dictionary which represents one row from a table.
For example my table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id          char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
    column1     varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    column2     integer
);
```

My dict looks like this:

```
mydict = {'id':'row11', 'column1':'abcdef', 'column2':4}
```

Now i am searching for an elegant generic way to update this data in the table with Psycopg2 similar to the way it is described for an insert statement here:

[Insert Python Dictionary using Psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461933/insert-python-dictionary-using-psycopg2)

Or is this not possible with an update-statement?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the update syntax if you know the names of the columns ahead of time?

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE test set column1=%(column1)s, column2=%(column2)s where id=%(id)s', mydict)
```

If you are looking for a solution where you don't know the columns ahead of time, you can use the [SQL string composition](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) module.  Just make sure you are always using parameterized queries and don't try to build the whole query yourself to avoid SQL injection issues.