# failed to decode json object when tried to do insertion on flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, error-handling, psycopg2

I tried to register new user to the local database on my flask app, and I used `psycopg2` to do database interaction. I learned that using `mogrify` would do data insertion on db, but I got following error at server endpoint:

```
{
  "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}
```

I could able to retrieve existing user from local database but I can't register a new users to same database table with `psycopg2`. can anyone point me how to make this work? anyway I could register/put the new user to a local database table? any thoughts? thanks

**my attempt in flask**:

Here is my attempt to register/put new user to local database table:

```
from flask_restplus import reqparse, fields, abort
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
from flask_restplus import Api, Namespace, Resource, fields, reqparse
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import psycopg2, json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app) 

credential_model = api.model('credential', {
    'username': fields.String(required=True),
    'password': fields.String(required=True)
})

credential_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
credential_parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
credential_parser.add_argument('password', type=str)

@api.route('/token')
class Token(Resource):
    @api.expect(credential_parser, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        args = credential_parser.parse_args()

        username = args.get('username')
        password = args.get('password')
        user = {'_id':username,
                'password': password 
        }
        columns = user.keys()
        values = [user[column] for column in columns]
        insert_statement = 'insert into authorized_user_table (%s) values %s'
        try:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.mogrify(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
        except:
            return {"message" : "{} has already been signed".format(username)}, 400
        return { 
            "message" : "{} Register Successfully".format(username), 
            "prediction_id" : username
            }, 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = psycopg2.connect(database='test_api', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost', port="5432")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**update: database table**:

```
 CREATE TABLE authorized_user_table (
   user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_name varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   user_email varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   user_password varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)

insert  into authorized_user_table(user_id,username,email,password) values 
(4,'Jen hardy','jhardy@gmail.com','password4');
```

for inserting new entries to databse table, I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461933/insert-python-dictionary-using-psycopg2) and [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461933/insert-python-dictionary-using-psycopg2), but still I can't register new user to local database table.

**update:error persist**:

I tried posted answer, but I still not able to insert new user to DB. how to make posted answer correct? any idea?

**objective**:

I just want to verify whether user exists in database if it is not, I want to register them in local db first, then set them authenticated users can access to flask app. how can I make this work? any possible thought? thanks

Comment: You want something like `cursor.execute(my_sql_statement, values)`.  `mogrify` produces the statement that would be executed, as a string, but it doesn't execute it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am sure your posted answer should work, but I still have same error, I assume insertion still failed, why?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I edited my post with same error message. seems your attempt should be fine, why I still have same error. how do we source the problem? thanks

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am running on windows machine actually.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I used flask-restplus where I filled up parameter like `username` and `password`, then hit `try out` which send those : `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/token?username=foo&password=bar'` to the server, and still I couldn't get away from the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213631/discussion-between-jyson-and-snakecharmerb).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I tried above command on curl, but still the same error. where am I mistaken? I posted a screenshot of curl output and server endpoint output on the discussion. thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hi, insertion query still failed to register new user to db. even I corrected this one: `cols = ','.join([str(sql.Identifier(x)) for x in user.keys()])`, and `insert_statement = 'insert into authorized_user_table %s values (%s)'`, still other TypeError persist. would you mind what would be right one? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works correctly.  In particular, it build the INSERT statement using the tools provided in [psycopg2.sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) and then *executes* the result.  `cursor.mogrify` returns the statement as a bytestring, but does not execute it.

This code assumes that dictionaries preserve insertion order.  This is true for CPython 3.6, and all implementations of Python 3.7.  If you are using an earlier version you will need to be sure that the keys and values are in synch when generating columns and values.

```
import sys
import traceback

from flask_restplus import reqparse, fields
from psycopg2 import sql
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from flask import Flask
import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

credential_model = api.model(
    "credential",
    {
        "username": fields.String(required=True),
        "password": fields.String(required=True),
    },
)

credential_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
credential_parser.add_argument("username", type=str)
credential_parser.add_argument("password", type=str)


@api.route("/token")
class Token(Resource):
    @api.expect(credential_parser, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        args = credential_parser.parse_args()

        username = args.get("username")
        password = args.get("password")
        user = {"user_name": username, "user_password": password}

        insert_statement = "insert into authorized_user_table ({}) values ({})"
        cols = sql.SQL(", ").join([sql.Identifier(x) for x in user.keys()])
        vals = sql.SQL(", ").join([sql.Placeholder() for _ in user.values()])
        insert_statement = sql.SQL(insert_statement).format(cols, vals)

        try:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(insert_statement, tuple(user.values()))
            # Commit/rollback added to make this work locally 
            # perhaps you are already doing this in your code
            db.commit()
        except: 
            # Print exception traceback if there's an error
            tb = sys.exc_info()
            traceback.print_exception(*tb)
            db.rollback()
            return {"message": "{} has already been signed".format(username)}, 400
        return (
            {
                "message": "{} Register Successfully".format(username),
                "prediction_id": username,
            },
            200,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = psycopg2.connect(database="test")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much, thanks for your precious time to help.